# Code to inscribe ordinal on bitcoin testnet using bitcoinjs-lib not working: transaction does not show as an inscription

Tags: bitcoin

After sending a *raw taproot transaction* intended to inscribe an Ordinal, it is not showing as an inscription by the ord explorer.

**Transaction**
669dc6ab5aada57e4a7a2b3a67c011d3f76c2a3f3a2ecc39ab8ed85bdb9aed44

**Tapleaf Script ASM** (written as usual in the witness data section):

```
1096be5c2ac24a8b51b3d3ea725ef56c07be9f1bdf1c1c3931789a98e77b9a3e OP_CHECKSIG OP_0 OP_IF 6f7264 OP_1 696d6167652f706e67 OP_0 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 OP_ENDIF
```

[Transaction shown in the ord explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVuFz.png)

The taproot transaction was created with a PSBT through bitcoinjs-lib.
The script spending path contains the opcode to check signature plus the ord envelope. As the content, a picture of mime-type image/png.

The submission of transaction is successful and the UTXO is correctly created with the ordinal envelope being saved in the witness section:

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "prev_hash": "ac1dd4708eba5d6f781de6039a885ab5c0cffbe2ec3ad6ffd475cdf8fe7ae73f",
      "output_index": 0,
      "output_value": 10000,
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "addresses": [
        "tb1pel6ww938pst9c8hrk685f2ef9lc6rr6gnmfeglxdpkv89d7fyx5saey5yh"
      ],
      "script_type": "pay-to-taproot",
      "age": 2440102,
      "witness": [
        "ed0541734e408cf6b9977234d5feefc92e96e09b41e326feaa66de59cdd2dca6ee8f04005201507edcd7deafe9f119d169377547bd34aae4777b853f1de17730",
        "201096be5c2ac24a8b51b3d3ea725ef56c07be9f1bdf1c1c3931789a98e77b9a3eac0063036f72645109696d6167652f706e67004da50189504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000036000000360203000000f12b824e0000000c504c544513b2c49fcfa4e8d46bf0faf9c8214e21000001544944415428cfa5d0bd4e02411007f039e5a03234d29033d7536172a5975d6288ed99b0a132f4f80a1a5f818207b08018d68247e08821b410432c7d85bb00b1e132eeba1f1c34263ad5fdb2f39fdb59805f8b31709895cb798f31eb2ee74341aae470ce272bc622c5a2206e196b59be6266c355cec707ec9730730c6b9c3ab8818a1e2d083ecd11e0425c2677ea1e529469aef29ede43f339cf221fc89b1b9ef091dcd2dc596c14c9dec8ee3b90bd7a5f316b247aed6b880d69c54445b8cbfbfba8ec1eeea3b27bbc8fca5f4d56addcbbdfe336cad1c7cc7ed7ccd3d13ff125c7a322405cd72d2f519d9218677e93a418ff3058bfcd3bcdb0d1500cbf60ddb923cbb622f98075b60b6f518d0aafa7ef9bdd95f3a946058071b223e98d1e0521c4f572aa471d95bfc029160af52795ad9f27f0e079978b58734bbdb3c7941a62ec95d0300812f04ee78da9a29f08c20c90c2bfea1b5745a5b1cf676d840000000049454e44ae42608268",
        "c136b27793a6093eee144bde7fa1496bce6bef309502b1e60a3868f6a63c86300eb480279345ba30ec3103edfb62f4f1f477738a3ac080ec407b74d79852ba2f79"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "value": 8000,
      "script": "5120986c3417f4ec8046d5d811015373f6e20c44ff12b9177de74d0980a3c2d44cfe",
      "addresses": [
        "tb1pnpkrg9l5ajqyd4wczyq4xulkugxyflcjhythme6dpxq28sk5fnlqfkjpca"
      ],
      "script_type": "pay-to-taproot"
    }
  ]
}
```

Still, the UTXO is not recognized as an ordinal by the explorer https://testnetexplorer.ordinex.io/tx/669dc6ab5aada57e4a7a2b3a67c011d3f76c2a3f3a2ecc39ab8ed85bdb9aed44

Comment: If this is about programming, please tag the language you are using. And add the relevant code.